# Randomly picking an increasing number of columns and summing up unique counts at each

Tags: r, vegan

I have two separate tab delimited data sets, `datA` and `datB`.

`datA` looks like this, with the entries in the `source` column going all the way to 10 million rows

```
source    Bin1    Bin2    Bin3    Bin4    Bin5
  A         1       1       2       2       3
  B         1       1       1       1       1
  C         0       0       0       1       0
  D         0       0       2       0       0
  E         4       0       0       1       0
  F         1       0       1       2       1
  G         0       5       0       0       0
```

`DatB` looks like this with up to 70 rows

```
Bins    readcounts
Bin1         100 
Bin2         40
Bin3         200
Bin4         150
Bin5         320
```

I would like to do the following in R

1. Randomly pick N samples from `datA` (i.e. one sample, then two samples, then three samples, etc, up to N). I want to bootstrap the process as well.
2. Calculate the sum of unique entries for the randomly picked samples (e.g. in `Bin1` (for one sample), `Bin3` and `Bin4` (for two samples), etc. such that

   - In the one-sample-case (`Bin1`) all entries would be unique
   - In the two-sample-case (`Bin3` and `Bin4`) the unique entries are those not shared by the two randomly picked samples (1 + 2 = 3).
3. Finally, I want to get the sum of read counts in `datB` related to the randomly picked samples in `datA`

The results would look like this:

```
RandomlyPicked_samples Sum_uniq_entries Total_readcounts
1         7        100
2         3        350 
..
```

However, I also want to get the mean and standard deviation for the bootstrap at each randomized step.

I can already get the sum of shared entries and unique entries for per column versus all using this commands in R

```
df <- data.frame(
    "source" = LETTERS[1:7],
    "Bin1" = c(1,1,0,0,4,1,0),
    "Bin2" = c(1,1,0,0,0,0,5),
    "Bin3" = c(2,1,0,2,0,1,0),
    "Bin4" = c(2,1,1,0,1,2,0),
    "Bin5" = c(3,1,0,0,0,1,0)
)

colsum_of_shared_entries <- colSums(df[which(apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x) all(x > 0))), -1])

colsum_of_shared_entries
# Bin1 Bin2 Bin3 Bin4 Bin5 
#  2    2    3    3    4

sum_of_unique_counts <- colSums(df[which(lapply(apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x) which(x > 0)), length) == 1),-1])

sum_of_unique_counts
# Bin1 Bin2 Bin3 Bin4 Bin5 
#   0    5    2    1    0
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any additional information should be added to the question. I've tried to do it for you, but please check.

Comment: You ortiginally had a Perl tag on this question but it has been removed. Why was it there? Do you want a Perl solution?

Comment: *" I want to bootstrap the process as well"* What does this mean?

Comment: Thanks Borodin, maybe the term isnt "bootstrap", but essentially I want to do the random picking like 100 times, and then calculate the mean (plus SD) for all randomly picked samples at each step (i.e., 1 sample, 2 samples, 3 samples, n samples)

Comment: I put "perl" since I thought there might also be an easier solution using Perl programming.

Comment: When you say you want to "sample" do you mean selecting a subset of rows? I don't get how the Bin1 - Bin5 relate to your concept of sampling (i.e what does "In the two-sample-case (Bin3 and Bin4) the unique entries are those not shared by the two randomly picked samples (1 + 2 = 3)." mean?)

Comment: Thanks TARehman. I want to randomly select a subset of column or column(s), such that I can calculate the sum of unique entries (in the rows) for these randomly selected columns disregarding the other columns. And I want also to repeat each random selection process such that I can calculate the mean and SD for each subset of column(s). For instance, based on one column, two columns, three columns, .... up to 70 columns.